# Get url when user is redirected because of authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, authorize.net

I'm building an app and on my `Checkout` controller I have the `[Authorize]` attribute. I want my users to be logged in before they checkout any orders.

However on this method:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string _returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = _returnUrl;

    return View();
}
```

The `_returnUrl` string is always empty. How can I provide the parameter with the current url browsed by the user?

Comment: Use `string returnUrl`. Also pass it to `[HttpPost]` method.

Comment: Simple as that. Thanks! Can you post it as an answer so that I might accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the query string parameter names in the Control Action methods so that model binder can pass them in correctly. So in you case it should be `string retrunUrl` not `string _returnUrl`.

```
...
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```